# pain quotidien...from where ?

Tags: expressions, traduction, étymologie, latin, grec

I had assumed that the name of this chain bread bakery was the phase 'daily bread'  taken from the Lord's Prayer, but I was recently in a French church and they do  not use 'pain quotidien', but instead say 'pain  de ce jour'.  Is there an older translation of the Lord's Prayer which is no longer in use which uses 'pain quotidien' ?

Comment: It depends which churches, some churches use "pain quotidien". It's only a new translation of the prayer.

Comment: The controversy about the translation is not specific to the French Language. You have an explanation in English [here](http://blog.adw.org/2010/06/the-hidden-and-mysterious-word-in-the-lords-prayer/). If you want to discuss this French Language is not appropriate. They might accept to discuss it on [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), I don't know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem of the translation from the Greek έπιούσιον has caused numerous discussions in lots of languages, and in English too. ["The difficulty is that the word  seems to exist nowhere else in ancient Greek and that no one really knows what it means."](http://blog.adw.org/2010/06/the-hidden-and-mysterious-word-in-the-lords-prayer/)

Comment: Hey, very interesting question, as the Latin translation is not so obvious. It explains why there are several versions of this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Everything starts with the greek ***έπιούσιον***. (1)
It has indeed been hard to translate as this word cannot be found anywhere else in other greek texts. Origenes suspected the Evangelists to have forged it... ex-nihilo... :-)

One possible understanding is : *what is necessary / suffices to keep our existence going* **and not only today but tomorrow and other days in the future.**

This understanding leading to the vulgate's latin translation :

- *Panem nostrum quotidianum* (Saint-Luc)

Keeping strict latin vocabulary and grammar, Luc's phrase should translate in french :

*Notre pain quotidien*

or, alternatively

*Notre pain de **chaque** jour*

***Chaque*** jour and actually not ***ce*** jour

However, as it appeared somehow *strange* to ask for having now altogether the bread of tomorrow and the one of following days in the future... *chaque* was changed to *ce*. asking then today for todays'bread only.

---

<sup>1 : I know I should copy the entire sentence however, I am too lazy to key in non roman chars with that suboptimal editor.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100901/discussion-on-answer-by-acoswt-pain-quotidien-from-where).